# How to find embedded entity?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am playing with Spring JPA, and not able to achieve below:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "User")    
    public class User implements Serializable {

        @Column
        private String name;

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
        private Address address;


        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Address getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(Address address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       protected long id;

       private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Location")    
    public class Location implements Serializable {

        @Column
        private String address;


        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       protected long id;

       private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   }
```

I have repositories for each domain model.

I want to get 'Address' by name such as 'findAddressByName()'. I have tried various different thing but always get User back. Can I get Address ? Is there a way to do ? Or that is how domain model specific works by default.

Comment: You're asking about a method findAddressByName(), but we have no idea hot it's implemented and where it's declared. It's supposed to return an Address, but you didn't post this entity. Post the relevant code.

Comment: I have it in repository similar to http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Comment: There is no "embedded" entity in what you present. You have a 1-1 to an Address yet if it was "embedded" then it would be `@Embedded` not `@OneToOne`. Also an embedded object has no "id" so you cannot "find" it without finding the object it is embedded into./

Comment: Thanks @NeilStockton